# What processes should be ioniced for a responsive desktop?

Tags: xorg, performance, system

My goal is to intelligently and permanently [ionice](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ionice) the processes on my desktop for responsiveness under heavy disk and network load. By permanently, I mean that any changes made to the system will persist across reboots. I want to eliminate situations where I can't move a window because disk bandwidth is saturated by a process that isn't in anyway serving my GUI.

There are hundreds of processes running on my system. Which ones could be run with class idle and which ones with class real time?

Is it a good idea to set the X and gnome-shell processes to class real time?

How about setting cupsd, avahi-daemon, gnome-screensaver, deluge, ntpd and backintime to class idle?

Here's a [list of the currently running processes on my system](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8817969/ps.txt.gz).

Comment: It's probably best to leave the processes be, and to recognize that any given computer has final resources. Giving more priority to some will take resources from the rest, making one process more responsive will make the rest less so.

Comment: @mike, do you mean _finite resources_ instead of _final resources_?

Comment: Yes, meant just that, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @mikewhatever Giving more priority to some and taking resources from the rest is exactly what I _want_ to do.

Comment: +1 Thought the question was misspelled but now I see it's actually something interesting. I'd like to see some improvements in this area, too. I have plenty of RAM, fast disks, etc, and yet still frequently face this same problem with responsiveness.

Comment: It's not that simple. Very smart people have worked for years to find a balance of process priorities. In comes Richard asking for a general advise on how to best steamroll and change it, without any info about the system or the problems. Great! I'd bet anything that changing nice values is the last thing you need to do. If your system gets slow, try to identify the bottlenecks. Get the Phoronix Test Suite and learn how to use it.

Comment: @mikewhatever I'm not talking about nice. Please reread my question. It's about **ionice**.

Comment: Well, the same, obviously, applies to ionice. :~)

Comment: @RichardAyotte Your ps.txt is binary. Couldn't read it.

Comment: @zuba It's gzipped and it used to automatically gunzip by the browser but DropBox must be doing something to HTTP headers. You can just download and gunzip it.

Comment: @Richard I see, but still can't

~/ > gunzip ~/ps.txt.gz 
gzip: ps.txt already exists; do you wish to overwrite (y or n)? y
~/ > cat ~/ps.txt 
l�/Ops.txt�\[F�~�� �}p�������`�N�v.��A�%�n�Txiu�a~��S��:�DK�dq���ߩ:u�uJ?�}��j�}��[��o������������^?��Y?�O��������G����w_[o�{�����/ʢ���?fY���^��!�7

Comment: Looks like DropBox re-gzipped it so it's been double gzipped! Gunzipping twice should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have better results tuning your VM (virtual memory) and writeback tendencies (swappiness) than going the ionice route, though if you must.

You can use **dpkg-divert** to permanently move the interested binaries like /usr/bin/firefox -> /usr/bin/firefox.orig. Then you're free to create a shell script in it's place like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# straight from the ionice manpage
ionice -c 2 -n 0 /usr/bin/firefox.orig $@
```

Pretty clear what the outcome is.

You could also go the **cgroups** route which is probably more cost effective in the long run, but you also open yourself up to a host of new performance based problems. Once you start metering resources you can easily starve out processes unintentionally, it'll do exactly what you tell it to do, even if you don't understand all the repercussion.

It looks like duplicity or deja-dup is running (rsync), which will of course suck up all your ioband width, some cpu too. Another option is to simply schedule it for when you're not in front of the computer, that's what I do. The best solution I've seen for io management is **dm-ioband** but it lives out of tree and has been under constant development for sometime.

I wish I had a blanket solution for you but there's no such thing with performance engineering. Here's a good guide from IBM, but you'll notice it that it's mostly "here's how you get started" for each subsystem, there aren't many "do this and be happy" recipes as they don't exist, every system's needs is different when it comes to performance tuning.

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4285.pdf